# Inheriting specifid methods in java

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, abstract, run-time-polymorphism

Is it possible in java to inherit some methods from the base class, but not all of them? Just to be clear, i will show you what I mean:
Suppose we have the base class Visitor

```
public abstract class Visitor {}
```

From Visitor we create 2 more Objects, Client and Companion:

```
public class Client extends Visitor {}
public class Companion extends Visitor {}
```

In Client, we create the method:

```
boolean has_Companion() {}
```

In order to achieve runtime polymorphism, we need to declare the method in Visitor as well:

```
abstract boolean has_Companion();
```

The problem is that since we declare the method in Visitor, Companion inherits it as well. We don't want that. When I compile I get the following error:

> The type Companion must implement the inherited abstract method Visitor.has_Companion()

There is no point in implementing the method has_Companion() for Companion because it will never be used. It's a waste of code. Can I avoid it in some way? Can the method has_Companion() be inherited only by Client, and not by Companion?

Comment: You don’t have to declare the method as abstract in the super class. Or create an interface instead of a superclass and let the method have a default implementation in the interface

Comment: *Can the method has_Companion() be inherited only by Client, and not by Companion?* **No**. It would not make sense to have a `Visitor` where the method is only available in **some** sub-classes.

Comment: You contradict yourself: first you say that you want to achieve polymorphism, meaning that client code must be able to know if the visitor has a companion without knowing if the visitor is a Client or a Companion, and then you say that has_Companion() will never be called on a Companion. If it will never be called on a Companion, it means that the client code knows that the visitor is a Client, and you thus don't need to declare it in Visitor.

Comment: @JBNizet I see. Maybe I have not understand the meaning of polymorphism. In my project I have a list of type Visitor, which contains Clients and Companions. From my implementation, I know when I have a Client or a Companion, but the variables are of type Visitor. I want to call has_Companion() via the Visitor variable, which in reality is a Client. Isn't that polymorphism?

Comment: Sure, but how can you know that the visitor is a Client, and not a Companion? And if you know, why not just use `((Client) visitor).hasCompanion()`?

Comment: I can be because the list is sorted in a specific way. I did not think about casting though! That solves my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use casting for this, there is a high probability your implementation is not appropriate. One usually puts two kinds of objects in the same data structure only if one needs to use them **the same way**. I think your question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/286538), meaning you are asking us because you think of a specific solution and that solution is not the correct one. Maybe you should include the whole [mcve] in your question and ask for advice on improving the solution.

Comment: @RealSkeptic the purpose of the project is to familiarize with these concepts. By doing that, I would essentially be asking for the solution to my problem. I guess I have to find it on my own. Could you tell me what else I should avoid doing, so that my implementation becomes more appropriate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that Java does not support what you're trying to do, but the good news is there are many ways to work around it.

**Idea 1**: Have `Companion` override `hasCompanion` and simply always return `false`.

**Idea 2**: Have `Visitor` provide an implementation of `hasCompanion` that simply always returns `false`.  Then Client will override `hasCompanion` with actual logic to determine if the Client has a companion.

**Idea 3**: Don't give a `hasCompanion` method to `Visitor` at all, but rather only have the method in `Client`.  Then the code has run-time type checking via the `instanceof` operator and calls the method on `Client` via casting.  Example:

```
if (visitor instanceof Client) {
    Client client = (Client) visitor;
    boolean hasCompanion = client.hasCompanion();
    // other logic
}
```

This is fake polymorphism at best and a very kludgy solution.  I would advise against doing this if possible.

**Idea 4**: Reconsider the design and refactor the type tree and how the code uses inheritance.  If it makes no sense to call `hasCompanion` on `Companion extends Visitor`, why is `hasCompanion` a method of `Visitor` at all?

Java does not support multiple inheritance, so interfaces are necessary:

```
public interface MightHaveCompanion {
    public boolean hasCompanion();
}

public abstract class Visitor {
    // methods that all Visitors must have
}

public class Client extends Visitor implements MightHaveCompanion {
    // overriding implementations of MightHaveCompanion and Visitor methods 
}

public class Companion extends Visitor {
    // overriding implementations of Visitor methods
}
```

Then calling code will have to change to use the types `MightHaveCompanion` or `Visitor` as necessary.  It's clear what methods belong to what types.  Make no mistake that on a larger project the amount of work to do this will scale, but it might result in cleaner code.